# jQuery - Using .split() on a number retrieved with .text() adds a lot of empty items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, text, split

I've retrieved an 8-digit number from a page using .text(), and then used .split("") on it so that I can rearrange it as I need. However, while it does get the number successfully, it adds 20-something empty items before and after it, along with a "↵" character at the start.

As a result the array looks like this:

```
["↵", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "2", "0", "1", "5", "0", "2", "2", "8", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
```

Instead of this:

```
["2", "0", "1", "5", "0", "2", "2", "8"]
```

I can still select the numbers that I need, I was just wondering if there was a way to 'clean it up' so that it behaved a bit more as expected.

The 8-digit number is the only thing inside the class that I've jQueried, and I've output just the queried value (without the .split()) as a test to confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `jQuery.trim()` to **"trim"** your string before the split

Comment: Thanks. Still no idea what's causing the extra whitespace, but this at least lets me make sure that it's consistent.

Comment: without having a look at the html code, I would guess that the html code is to blame and that the source of the tag would contain a lot of space/tabs.

Answer (score 0):

you can try jquery grep function like this

```
arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function( a ) {
return a !== "";
});
```

Find more detail over here : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/